# Selecting pandas columns by datatype

Tags: pandas, dataframe, types

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this...

[image]

with the highlighted floats occurring in the `type` column, while all the rest are `str`, as shown in the image. There are about 70 rows like this, scattered up and down the dataframe, and there around 29000 rows in total. I want to select the rows which have a `float` in that column, rather than a `str`. I've tried

```
floats = MgII_df.loc[type(MgII_df.type) != str]
```

which returns `KeyError: True`
and

```
floats = MgII_df.loc[-0.8 < MgII_df.type <= 62]
```

which returns `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`.

How can I select out the rows with floats in this column?

Comment: `MgII_df.loc[pd.to_numeric(MgII_df.type, errors='coerce').notna()]`?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko `floats = MgII_df[MgII_df.type.apply(type) != str]` returns an empty dataset.

Comment: I think that @ayhan's solution is the way to go.

Comment: @ayhan That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get float value by checking if a decimal value exists in a string. It's quite naive, but should work in your case.

```
# check if a decimal exists
floats = MgII_df[MgII_df['type'].apply(lambda x: '.' in x)]
floats = floats['type'].astype(float)
```

Comment: You are right. I saw `type` column has some `QSO` string value, and string > float, so probably it is already str type. @Jim can further clarify.